# sending exit code when raise the "SIGUSR1" signal

Tags: process, operating-system, signals

I am Trying to send the exit code of child proccess when raise "SIGUSR1"
i worte  a handler that waits for the process but it does not recive the exit code correctly
istead it recives -1

this is my code at main

```
void main()
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
        perror("error in forking");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("\ni am child and my pid %d\n", getpid());
        raise(SIGUSR1);
        exit(100);
    }
    sleep(5);
    printf("\nnow i am the parent and my  = %d\n ", getpid());
}
```

and this is the handler code

```
void handler(int signunm)
{

    int pid, stat_loc;

    pid = wait(&stat_loc);
    if (!(stat_loc & 0x00FF))
        printf("\nI am called with the process %d with value %d\n", pid, stat_loc >> 8);
}
```

and the output something like

```
i am child and my pid 45892

I am called with the process -1 with value 4

now i am the parent and my  = 45891
```

and it should be `100` not `-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `kill(PPID, SIGUSR1)` function not the `raise(SIGUSR1)` function so you send a signal to the parent to handle it not to the child itself. You can get the `PPID` through calling `getppid()`